# How can I specify a Primary Category in a Moblog submission?

Tags: primary-category

The EE Moblog syntax allows you to set categories and multiple categories via a {category} tag pair in the email submitting your content.

That's fine unless you have Primary Category set for that channel. In that case, the content - although it's added to the channel by the Moblog module - won't render in a channel entries loop unless a Primary Category is set.

Is there a workaround (besides manually editing the channel entry)? Would Primary Category have to hook into Moblog submissions to identify a primary category tag for this to work seamlessly?

Thanks

Steve